# How can I get a div to increase height instead of jumping below my left floating div first and then increasing height?

Tags: css, css-float

I have two divs inline in a container, left one should be fixed size, and the right one should use the remaining width. If the right one contains little text it works fine, if it contains more text i want it to expand in height.
What happens is that right one jumps below left one first if there is too much text, and then expands in height.

In short: I want both elements always in same line, no matter how much text is in right element

Code below, fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/t4dg95ov/

I think/hope I just miss something trivial, but I cant find it.

```css
.container {
  background-color: purple;
}

.left-element {
  min-height: 113px;
  width: 85px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-element {
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-height: 113px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-element">left</div>
  <div class="right-element">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floats, you could give flexbox a try:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: purple;
}

.left-element {
  flex: 0 0 85px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-element {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-element">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
  </div>
  <div class="right-element">
    ore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit: If you must use floats, just could set the max width of right div like so:

```
max-width: calc(100% - 85px);
```

Comment: I appreciate your input, but i would much rather like to use more traditional stuff. There is more stuff there already which i dont want to change in flex, the example is simplified. This is the first time i touch anything related with CSS/web and its already a full website with a custom theme for an NGO. (read: I am afraid to use stuff I dont fully understand yet)

Comment: Use tables then :) (Update: I meant use `display: table-cell`... you could create table like layout with css without using table/tr/td)

Comment: Same question than on the other suggestion: WHY does this max-width work? This css looks more and more like witchcraft to me.. (I feel lucky again that my day job is machine control software and not web)

Comment: If you knew the width of parent say 700px then second column would be 615px... but I guessed that you don't know its width and `calc` is useful in such cases. 100% - 85px means subtract 85px from parent's width.

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear in my question: I was wondering why the whole thing works when specifying a max-width vs. why is it not working without? I mean i had width: auto, in my understanding this should do the same - automatically use the remaining space, so 100%-85px.

Comment: No. Floats (and inline blocks) can grow as much as their content but not wider than viewport (unless e.g. when they contain a very wide image or long unwrappable text); if they get wider than remaining width on the line they're simply pushed down on the next line.

Comment: Hm, well, I see that it works this way, but I still dont understand it completely. There is no need to get wider than the remaining viewport since it contains only wrappable text. But well, thats how its implemented in CSS. Thank you again for your help and your insights

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving fixed widths, you can give in %. Below solution will work fine.

```css
.container {
  background-color: purple;
}

.left-element {
  min-height: 113px;
  width: 12%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-element {
  margin-top: 0px;
  min-height: 113px;
  width: 88%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-element">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
  </div>
  <div class="right-element">
    ore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Now I am curious WHY this works and a fixed one does not. Does not solve my problem though, left one actually should contain a picture which is fixed width, should not move and not have whitespace to the right one

Comment: In case you want to keep fixed widths, right div should also get a width.

Answer (score 1):

You can also opt for css grid. You would implement it like this:

```css
.container { 
display: grid; 
grid-template-columns: 85px 1fr; 
grid-template-rows: 1fr; 
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px; 
background-color: purple;
}
.left-element {
  min-height: 113px;
  background-color: green;
}

.right-element {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-element">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
  </div>
  <div class="right-element">
    ore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
  </div>
</div>
```

You can even customize or adjust easily here: https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/

If you want to stick to something "traditional" you can also consider a borderless table. Like this:

```css
.container {
  background-color: purple;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.left-element {
  min-height: 113px;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 85px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 0px;
}

.right-element {
  vertical-align:top;
  min-height: 113px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
  border:0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
<tr>
  <td class="left-element">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit a
  </td>
  <td class="right-element">
    ore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
    eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```